# How to import c++ header file from one folder to another in android studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, import

I am currently working in Android Studio 3.0.
I have header files in path:

```
app\libs\Superpowered\sound.h
```

I need to import this header file in c++ file in path:

```
\app\src\main\jni\play.c++
```

I tried the below code but I am getting errors.

```
#include "../libs/Superpowered/sound.h"
```

error is:

```
'../libs/Superpowered/sound.h' file not found
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

how about use "libs/Superpowered/sound.h"  or add the path "libs/Superpowered/" in your mk file and only include "sound.h".

Comment: Hi,I tried both .in mk file ,it is again showing error.if the path is used , it accepts but when I try to build.it gives error os undefined reference to header.

Comment: is the source file in same dir? it maybe not find source file.

Comment: It is in same folder app.the files are in folder inside this as shown in path.

Comment: if could, please post your compile log. i think your mk file also not find "sound.cpp"